# Spring Boot/Velocity Unable to find resource Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, velocity

I am trying to make a Spring Boot application work with a set of Velocity Templates. I googled the forum a bit, found some info, I tried to implement them, but unable to get it to work. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong. I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to find resource '/VBS Template Files/StandardVariables.vm'
```

I have attached my folder structure in Eclipse, I tried all possible combinations of the path. But nothing seems to work.

By the way, my controller class is in a different project. Would that cause an issue? [image]

I have added a properties file:

```
#VelcoityConfiguration
spring.velocity.resourceLoaderPath=classpath:/VBS Template Files/
spring.velocity.prefix=
spring.velocity.suffix=.vm
spring.velocity.cache=false
spring.velocity.check-template-location=false
spring.velocity.content-type=text/html
spring.velocity.charset=UTF-8
spring.velocity.properties.input.encoding=UTF-8
spring.velocity.properties.output.encoding=UTF-8
```

The error is thrown from this line:

```
for (String table : tableNames) {
    mergeTemplate(table, "ISO-8859-1", velocityContext, writer);
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
2018-03-20 23:21:38.960  INFO 16728 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.c.ConfigGeneratorApplication         : Started ConfigGeneratorApplication in 3.336 seconds (JVM running for 4.542)
2018-03-20 23:21:53.419  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-20 23:21:53.420  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-03-20 23:21:53.445  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 25 ms
2018-03-20 23:21:53.748  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.palconfig.ActionMonitor            : PAL Config request contained invalid request data
2018-03-20 23:21:53.916  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.v.utilities.VelocityBuilderAction  : VelocityBuilderAction processAction() started
2018-03-20 23:21:53.916  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.v.utilities.VelocityBuilderAction  : Starting
2018-03-20 23:21:53.916  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.v.utilities.VelocityBuilderAction  : ProcessConfigRequest received ...
2018-03-20 23:21:53.917  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.v.utilities.VelocityBuilderAction  : ConfigRequest
2018-03-20 23:21:53.917  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.v.utilities.VelocityBuilderAction  : Device = SAM01
2018-03-20 23:22:25.601 ERROR 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.velocity                      : ResourceManager : unable to find resource '/VBS Template Files/StandardVariables.vm' in any resource loader.
2018-03-20 23:25:01.886 ERROR 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.v.utilities.VelocityJythonAdapter  : Error
2018-03-20 23:25:01.888  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.v.utilities.VelocityBuilderAction  : VBS has returned the following data ...
2018-03-20 23:25:01.888  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.v.utilities.VelocityBuilderAction  : 
2018-03-20 23:25:01.889  INFO 16728 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.a.l.v.utilities.VelocityBuilderAction  : VelocityBuilderAction processAction() ended
```

Comment: add complete stack trace of exception

Comment: @catchingUp Unfortunately that is all I see on the console. Not enough info.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `resourceLoaderPath` to `/VBS Template Files/`, then you must not ask for `/VBS Template Files/StandardVariables.vm` otherwise Velocity will search for `/VBS Template Files/VBS Template Files/StandardVariables.vm`.

So you only need to ask for `StandardVariables.vm`.